# combine two rdd in pyspark operation when filtering operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have to do an rdd based operation. My operation as follow;

```
test1 = rdd.filter(lambda y: (y[0] >= y[1])) # condition 1
test2 = rdd.filter(lambda y: (y[0] < y[1])) # condition 2
result1 = test1.collect()
result2 = test2.collect()
print('(',len(result1),',',len(result2),')')
```

Can I combine these two conditions into one rdd?
I tried something like this;

```
test3 = test1.zip(test2).collect()
```

But it didnt work.  e.g. if I apply `collect()` to test1 rdd, I get a list. Then I find the length of that list. Similarly I do the same thing for test2 rdd. Now the question is can I do this in one shot? finding lengths of the lists in one go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can map two conditions into a tuple and convert the resulting boolean values into integers, then do reduce:

```
# create a sample of rdd with 30 elements
import numpy as np
from operator import add

rdd = sc.parallelize([*map(tuple, np.random.randint(1,100,(30,2)))])

rdd.map(lambda y: (int(y[0] >= y[1]), int(y[0] < y[1]))) \
   .reduce(lambda x,y: tuple(map(add, x,y)))
#(19, 11)
```

Comment: Great jxc!! This is what I was looking for. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to get only one result instead of 2?

```
   test = rdd.filter(lambda y: (y[0] >= y[1]) and ((y[0] < y[1])))
```

Comment: thanks Souha. But this doesnt help. I would like to see the result as like in my print statement (as tuples).

Comment: Can you give me an example of the input you entered so I can try the full code?

Comment: And please provide more details about the output you want to see it would help people answer your question.

Comment: for e.g.. if I apply collect() to test1 rdd, I get a list. Then I find the length of that list. Similarly I do the same thing for test2 rdd. Now the question is can I do this in one shot? finding lengths of the lists in one go..